# useForm - disable submit temporary

Tags: reactjs, forms

**What I do:** I use `useForm` with some fields - one of them is for file uploading. It is a custom field that uses the `Controller`.

**The problem:**
The Upload field is optional but once user decide to use it *i would like to permit the form submiting while it is uploading the file*

So the question is how to invalidate form or permit the submission for a while and then enable that back.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

1. You can try using touchedfields of react-hook-form and if fileinput is touched and no value you can disable the submit.
2. checking if file input is focused you can disable submit.